# How to display true if find is not empty

Tags: linux, bash

I am very new to bash. I have just started to learn last week. I am trying to search for a file name.
How can I display a message if the file is found?

this is what i have but it keeps saying 'no'

```
echo ' [Enter] a file name '    
read findFile

if [[ -n $(find /$HOME -type f -name "findFile") ]]
then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

Comment: `$findFile` instead of `findFile` in the `find` command?

Comment: thanks alot. i spent 30 minutes on this and never noticed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few issues:

1. Use `var=` or `read var` when defining a variable, but `$var` when using it.
2. There is no reason to keep searching after finding a file, so do something like below, where `find` will `-quit` after finding a single file and return it as a result of the `-print`

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo ' [Enter] a file name '    
   read findFile
   if [[ -f $(find "$HOME" -type f -name "$findFile" -print -quit) ]]; then
       echo 'yes'
   else
       echo 'no'
   fi
   ```

   Note that the option `-quit` will work on GNU and FreeBSD operating systems (which means this will work in most cases), but for example, you will need to change it to `-exit` on NetBSD.
   You can see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62883/243375) from Unix/Linux StackExchange for details on this option.

Also note, per [Adaephon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805204/how-to-display-true-if-find-is-not-empty/22805527#comment34778178_22805527), that although the `/` is not needed in front of `$HOME`, it's not wrong and the files will still be found .

Comment: Actually (at least on Linux) `/$HOME` does exist and is the same as `$HOME`. Multiple `/` in paths are just handled as a single `/`. Although initial `//` has a special meaning on some Unices, this is not the case for Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Use `wc` to count the number of lines in the find output:

```
if [ $(find $HOME -type f -name "thisFile" 2> /dev/null | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

the `2> /dev/null` part hides possible error messages.