# How to check if find command didn't find anything?

Tags: linux, bash, find, suse

I know that is possible to use for loop with find command like that

```
for i in `find $something`; do (...) done
```

but I want to use find command with "if".

I am trying to create progress comments (and log files later) about removed files by my script. I need to check if

```
find /directory/whatever -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +$DAYS
```

found something or not. If not I want to say echo 'You don't have files older than $DAYS days' or something like this ;)

How I can do that in shell script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display true if find is not empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22805204/how-to-display-true-if-find-is-not-empty)

Comment: That question checks contents. This question asks if find does not find the file.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Count the number of lines output and store it in a variable, then test it:

```
lines=$(find ... | wc -l)
if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
...
fi
```

Comment: is this for `tcsh`?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz No, in `tcsh`, you would need backticks, so `lines='find ... | wc -l'` but replacing the single quotes with backticks.

Answer (score 19):

To use the `find` command **inside** an **if condition**, you can try this one liner :

```
 [[ ! -z `find 'YOUR_DIR/' -name 'something'` ]] && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Example of use :

```
 [prompt] $ mkdir -p Dir/dir1 Dir/dir2/ Dir/dir3                 
 [prompt] $ ls Dir/
 dir1  dir2  dir3
 [prompt] $ [[ ! -z `find 'Dir/' -name 'something'` ]] && echo "found" || echo "not found"
 not found
 [prompt] $ touch Dir/dir3/something
 [prompt] $ [[ ! -z `find 'Dir/' -name 'something'` ]] && echo "found" || echo "not found"
 found
```

Alternatively, `-n` can be used instead of `! -z`, for example:

```bash
[[ -n `find $dir -name $filename` ]] && echo found
```

From `man test`:

```
-n STRING
       the length of STRING is nonzero
```

Comment: Why use `! -z` instead of `-n`?

Answer (score 12):

Exit 0 is easy with find, exit >0 is harder because that usually only happens
with an error. However we can make it happen:

```
if find -type f -exec false {} +
then
  echo 'nothing found'
else
  echo 'something found'
fi
```

Comment: This is not correct. The question asks how to return false if it DOES NOT find anything. -exec will only run if it does find something so this would never work properly.

Comment: @deltaray: This answer returns false when files are found and true when they're not. Simply negate the result with a `!` or use the then/else as shown which is set up in a negated form.

Comment: The best answer, since once it finds an element the find statement does not continue searching for files.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
if test $(find . -name "pattern" | wc -c) -eq 0
then
    echo "missing file with name pattern"
fi
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted to compare one dir against another

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do this in a single line if possible, but couldn't see a way to get find to change its exit code without causing an error.

However, with your specific requirement, the following should work:

```
find /directory/whatever -name '*.tar.gz' -mtime +$DAYS | grep 'tar.gz' || echo "You don't have files older than $DAYS days"
```

This works by passing the output of find into a `grep` for the same thing, returns a failure exit code if it doesn't find anything, or will success and echo the found lines if it does.

Everything after `||`  will only execute if the preceding command fails.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the output of `find` might be dangerous if your filenames contain spaces. If you're sure they don't, you can store the result of `find` to an array, and check its size to see there were any hits:

```
results=( $(find -name "$something") )
if (( ${#results[@]} )) ; then
    echo Found
else
    echo Not found
fi
for file in "${results[@]}" ; do
   # ...
done
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Sure, it is. I just copied the OP.

Comment: I don't have spaces in names, because I'm creating all of that files with other script, thanks! ;)