# Find files and tar in a for if statement

Tags: bash, scripting

Trying to create an if statement which will search with a username in a location to see if a tar has been done already. If not create said tar in a location. For some reason, my find is running through the *then* echo command regardless if there is a file in that location or not.

```
USER_LIST="$(awk '{print $3}' usernamefile.txt)" 
for USER_NAME in $USER_LIST;do
   echo $USER_NAME
   if find /location/to/store/tarfile -type f -iname $USER_NAME; 
    then
        echo "tar file has been found for" $USER_NAME "/location/to/store/tarfile" `date` >> /logfile/log.txt   
    else
    FILE_LOC="$(awk -v $USER_NAME=$3 '{print $5;}' usernamefile.txt)" 
    tar -czvf ${USER_NAME}.tar.gz /location/to/put/tar/file $FILE_LOC
        echo "tar exit code:" $? $USER_NAME "has been archived" `date` >> /logfile/log.txt

    fi
done
```

I'm not sure why but if the find doesn't *find* anything. Surely it should move onto the else part of the script? the plan is creating tar files such as `<username>.tar.gz`

Comment: Sounds too broad. Please limit the scope of your question to a single, clear problem and provide a [mre].

Comment: Not sure how much more i can limit it, thought it was pretty obvious  ...  I'm trying to work out why the find is always pushing to then and not moving on to else regardless if it can find the file or not.

Comment: **find**'s exit status doesn't depend on whether it has found a file or not, read the manual, especially the **EXIT STATUS** section. Besides, if there is a problem with the **find** command, you don't need to include the whole script; and *My program is working, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this?* is off-topic unless you clearly state what's wrong with your program.

Comment: Your `if` statement should be something like that: `if find ...args... | grep -q . ; then ...` or `if [ -n "$(find ...args...)" ]; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that using `test` command would work best for my needs with either a `-f` or a `-e` flag.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you don't know how to capture the result of `find`: this gives a list of files, obeying the conditions you add in the `find` statement. So, best thing to do, is to count them: if there are none, then there are no such files, so you get something like:

```
if $(find /location/to/store/tarfile -type f -iname $USER_NAME | wc -l) 
then
  ...
```

The `| wc -l` reads the number of found files. If a file has been found, the result is not equal to 0, so it gets interpreted as `TRUE`.

Comment: If this is what OP was looking for, then this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156902/how-to-check-if-find-command-didnt-find-anything), you've been around long enough to know you shouldn't answer duplicates. Hence the downvote

Comment: @oguzismail Surely SOF is a place for communication and collaboration. If there is a duplicate i didn't find it when I previously searched for my question. Hence where we are here.Thanks to you and Dominique i now know what my issue is.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with **asking** duplicate questions, they can be deleted easily. But **answering** duplicates is harmful in that it fragments valuable information.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. The `if` statement won't work like that.

Comment: Apart from checking out exit status' can you recommend a different command